# How to show some files name from an array on a label one by one in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My code:

```
//Array with number of files
string[] A = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\ggg\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    Label files = ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)._pnlScanResults.FindName("lblFiles") as Label;
    files.Content = cGlobal.filesArray[i].ToString();
    //need some time to see file name one by one on label.....how ??
}
```

Comment: FindName of a control on a form is very slow.  I usually make my own List<>. : List<Label> labels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3 };  Then search for label name in list.

Comment: Can't understand what you are looking for exactly. Can you post an example of your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lbl` is the `Label` to show filenames.

```
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Lbl.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Lbl.Content = i + " : " + A[i]; });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Now i also want to display a progress bar for files in my loop. as loop exits, progress bar should be completed.